# TFS The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, .net, tfs, msbuild, aspnet-merge

I have created an automated build process using TFS which builds a web application.

As part of this process a batch file is used to call ASP Merge to merge my web pages into one dll. I'm using the TFS activity, Invoke Process to do this.

The following is a screenshot of what is output in the TFS build window:
[TFS Build Output](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F61A92EE32D33B4C!1174&authkey=!AHnpJsp4CuivjyA&v=3&ithint=photo,.JPG)

Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I too would like a solution to this issue: "Invoking batch file failed because it is being used by another process". I cant figure out what process it blocking this action from completing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by **removing the "Start /high /wait" command** that I had in place to start the aspnet_merge tool in a separate window. The reason this was being done is because in a **local script** we were compiling the code files first using **aspnet_compiler** before running aspnet_merge.
I also had to split the rest of the file out into a different command file as it was deleting config files I needed.